# JXcore_cordova plugin nodejs android issue

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, plugins, jxcore

using express 4.12.3 and cordova 5.0.0, and [jxcore-cordova plugin](https://github.com/jxcore/jxcore-cordova):

Writing this simple segment of code doesn't work:

```
 var http = require('http');
 var express = require('express');
 var app = express();
 var server = http.createServer(app);
 server.listen(1337);
 app.get('/',function(req,res){
   res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
   res.end();
 });
```

The return error is:

> 5611-5648/com.example.hello E/jxcore-log﹕   etag@/data/data/com.example.hello/files/node_modules/express/node_modules/etag/index.js:55:1  setHeader@/data/data/com.example.hello/files/node_modules/express/node_modules/send/index.js:739:15
>   SendStream.prototype.send@/data/data/com.example.hello/files/node_modules/express/node_modules/send/index.js:507:3   onstat@/data/data/com.example.hello/files/node_modules/express/node_modules/send/index.js:600:5
>   makeCallback/<@fs.js:83:12
>   fs.stat@fs.js:718:7
>   sendFile@/data/data/com.example.hello/files/node_modules/express/node_modules/send/index.js:590:3
>   SendStream.prototype.pipe@/data/data/com.example.hello/files/node_modules/express/node_modules/send/index.js:479:3
>   sendfile@/data/data/com.example.hello/files/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1029:3
>   sendFile@/data/data/com.example.hello/files/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:402:3
>   @/data/data/com.example.hello/files/app.js:24:5
>   handle@/data/data/com.example.hello/files/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:82:5
>   next@/data/data/com.example.hello/files/node_mod

However, this code works fine:
using fs module:

```
fs.readFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html',function(err,html){
  app.get('/',function(req,res){
    res.write(html);
    res.end();
  });
});
```

Tested on Android Studio and eclipse on both Linux Mint and Windows 7. The plugin works fine on iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Try without `res.end`:

```
app.get('/',function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
});
```